# JavaScript syntax error, but only in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, syntax-error

I am getting an error with the javascript below in IE 7 and 8 - the error code I get is:

Message: Expected ')'
Line: 1
Char: 19
Code: 0

The offending JS is:

```
var lct_days = 0;
var lct_hours = 0;
var lct_minutes = 0;
var lct_seconds = 0;

function calc_data(dateandtime) {
    dateandtime = datetime.split(" ");
    tempdate = dateandtime[0].split("/");
    temptime = dateandtime[1].split(":");

    var seconds = 1000;
    var minutes = seconds * 60;
    var hours = minutes * 60;
    var days = hours * 24;
    var years = days * 365;

    var db_time = new Date(tempdate[0], tempdate[1] - 1, tempdate[2], temptime[0], temptime[1], 00);
    var now_time = new Date();
    db_time = db_time.getTime();
    now_time = now_time.getTime();
    var lctresult = db_time - now_time;

    lct_years = Math.floor(lctresult / years);
    lct_days = Math.floor(lctresult / days) - (lct_years * 365);
    lct_hours = Math.floor(lctresult / hours) - (lct_days * 24) - (lct_years * 365 * 24);
    lct_minutes = Math.floor(lctresult / minutes) - (lct_hours * 60) - (lct_days * 24 * 60) - (lct_years * 365 * 24 * 60);
    lct_seconds = Math.floor(lctresult / seconds) - (lct_minutes * 60) - (lct_hours * 60 * 60) - (lct_days * 60 * 24 * 60) - (lct_years * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    singlebox = false;
    if (lct_years > 99) {
        lct_years = 99;
    }
    if (lct_days > 99) {
        singlebox = true;
    }
    if (lct_years < 0) lct_years = 0;
    if (lct_days < 0) lct_days = 0;
    if (lct_hours < 0) lct_hours = 0;
    if (lct_minutes > 60) lct_minutes = 60;
    if (lct_minutes < 0) lct_minutes = 0;
    if (lct_seconds < 0) lct_seconds = 0;
}

function setlct(datetime) {
    calc_data(datetime);
    if (lct_years == 0) {
        jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(1)').removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
        if (lct_days == 0) {
            jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(2)').removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
            if (lct_hours == 0) {
                jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(3)').removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
                if (lct_minutes == 0) {
                    jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(4)').removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
                    //if(lct_seconds==0)
                    //jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(5)').removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (jQuery('.LCT').find('div.type').siblings().length == 5) {
        jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(1) .bg p').html(lct_years);
        jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(2) .bg p').html(lct_days);
        jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(3) .bg p').html(lct_hours);
        jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(4) .bg p').html(lct_minutes);
        jQuery('.LCT').find('div:nth-child(5) .bg p').html(lct_seconds);

        if (jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(2)').hasClass('big')) {
            if (singlebox == true) jQuery('.LCT  div:nth-child(2).big .bg p').addClass("evensmaller");
        }
        if (jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(2).medium').hasClass('medium')) {
            if (singlebox == true) jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(2).medium .bg p').addClass("evensmaller");
        }
        if (jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(2).small').hasClass('small')) {
            if (singlebox == true) jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(2).small .bg p').addClass("evensmaller");
        }
    } else {
        if (lct_years != 0 && lct_years > 0) {
            jQuery('.LCT').find('div .bg p').html(lct_years);
            jQuery('.LCT div .type').html('YEARS');
        } else if (lct_days != 0 && lct_days > 0) {
            jQuery('.LCT').find('div .bg p').html(lct_days);
            jQuery('.LCT div .type').html('DAYS');
        } else if (lct_hours != 0 && lct_hours > 0) {
            jQuery('.LCT').find('div .bg p').html(lct_hours);
            jQuery('.LCT div .type').html('HOURS');
        } else if (lct_minutes != 0 && lct_minutes > 0) {
            jQuery('.LCT').find('div .bg p').html(lct_minutes);
            jQuery('.LCT div .type').html('MINUTES');
        } else if (lct_seconds != 0 && lct_seconds > 0) {
            jQuery('.LCT').find('div .bg p').html(lct_seconds);
            jQuery('.LCT div .type').html('SECONDS');
        }

        if (jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(1).big').length != 0) {
            if (singlebox == true) jQuery('.LCT  div:nth-child(1).big .bg p').addClass("evensmaller");
        }
        if (jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(1).medium').length != 0) {
            if (singlebox == true) jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(1).medium .bg p').addClass("evensmaller");
        }
        if (jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(1).small').length != 0) {
            if (singlebox == true) jQuery('.LCT div:nth-child(1).small .bg p').addClass("evensmaller");
        }
    }

    var lctTimer = setInterval("setlct(" + datetime + ");", 1000);
    clearTimeout(lctTimer);
}
var lctTimer = '';
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    datetime = $('input.lct_datetime').val();
    lctTimer = setInterval('setlct(\'' + datetime + '\');', 1000);
});
```

Any ideas??? Not sure what the error I am getting relates too... it does not seem to make sense?

P.S. It is a live countdown timer clock plugin for WordPress > http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/live-countdown-timer/

Comment: the code review stackexchange site will be helpful I think

Comment: have you tried running your code through jsHint or similar tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure but try changing lines:

```
var lctTimer = setInterval("setlct(" + datetime + ");", 1000);
```

to

```
var lctTimer = setInterval(function() {
   setlct(datetime);
},1000);
```